# Conversion of query from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am converting our project database from SQL Server to MySQL, the DB conversion has done already.
 But while executing some queries I'm getting some errors.

I'm using ColdFusion 8, MySQL 5.

Here is one example:

```
SELECT i.ID, s.Name, i.OccurredOn, i.MinorProblemID, 
  i.MajorProblemID, i.Problem, i.Motivation, i.Strategy1, 
  i.Strategy2, i.Strategy3, i.Decision, 
  COALESCE(CAST(s.Grade as int),-5) as Grade, i.LocationID, 
  l.Display as StartMonth, l.OrderBy as StartMonthOrder, 
  i.StudentID, u.ID as SourceID, 
  replace(u.FirstName+' '+u.LastName,'''','`') as Source,
  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace( 
      ltrim(replace(CAST(OccurredOn as varchar(100)),CAST(OccurredOn 
      as varchar(12)),'')),':1',':0'),':2',':0'),':3',':0'),':4',':0'),
      ':5',':0'),':05',':00'),':00',':00 ') as StartHour 
FROM ViewIncidents i 
JOIN Students s ON i.StudentID = s.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users u ON i.UserID = u.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup l ON l.LookupCode = 'SchoolMonths' 
  AND l.Value = CAST(OccurredOn as varchar(3)) 
WHERE i.OccurredOn > '7/1/2012' 
AND i.OccurredOn >= '7/1/2012' 
ORDER BY i.OccurredOn DESC
```

**It works fine in SQL Server but fails in MySQL:**

> Error Executing Database Query.
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int),-5) as Grade, i.LocationID, l.Display as StartMonth, l.OrderBy as Star' at line 2

Pls help me with the migration of db from mssql to mysql and along with the easiest way to change the queries.

Thanks,

Prathamesh

Comment: Do you really write all of your queries with no carriage returns? It makes for an unreadable mess FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenation in mysql is done by using `CONCAT()`

```
replace(CONCAT(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName), '''', '`') AS Source
```

when casting instead of `INT` use `SIGNED` (*or UNSIGNED*)

```
COALESCE(CAST(s.Grade AS SIGNED), - 5) AS Grade,
```

instead of `VARCHAR` use `CHAR`

```
CAST(OccurredOn AS CHAR(100))
```

all others are fine except the casting and concatenation.

Comment: thanks @JW...Can u tell me easiest way to handle such queries? i mean, a brief on the syntactical changes in mssql and mysql?

Comment: the two servers have differences in terms of stored functions. and you will have to manually check for the syntax.

Comment: @JW champion of Champions SQl

Comment: @Mudassirhasan you're wrong `:)` there are many sleeping wizards of sql out there `:)`

Comment: well, i made the changes suggested by u @ j W, query worked without any error, but i'm getting an empty set as a result. :(

Comment: can you give sample records with you desired result? my guess is you're getting emprty result because of your filtering condition. try removing the `WHERE` clause if it returns records.

Comment: ID-6039
NAME-Hemel, Braden E. 
Occured on-2013-01-26 08:00:00.000 
MinorProblemID-61 
MajorProblemID-NULL 
Problem-Minor - Defiance/ Disrespect/ non-compliance 
Motivation-Avoid peers 
Strategy1-Behavior Contract Strategy2-NULL Strategy3-NULL Decision-Saturday School Grade-1 LocationID-26 StartMonth-January StartMonthOrder-7 StudentID-12977 SourceID-481 Source-Dorothee Hamm StartHour-8:00 AM 

This is what i get when i run the query in sql server. Sorry for improper arrangement

Comment: you can add that along with your question or create it on http://www.sqlfiddle.com